# How do I pass null as a value in a POST request on python?

Tags: python, post, request, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST request with params that contain **null** values and None just gets ignored. Besides that, I'm unsure about whether or not **False** is sent as **false**.

For example:

```
requests.post("http://myurl.com/address/", data = {"parentValue":{"value1":False,"value2":None}})
```

and the required params server-side are

```
{"parentValue":{"value1":false, "value2":null}}
```

**tl;dr:** I need **false** and **null** on the server side as params from a POST request, how do I send them using Python requests?

Comment: A tool such as fiddler, wireshark, or tcpdump (linux) will allow to to see the exact traffic sent -- so you won't have to guess.

Comment: You could try `json.dumps()` on your data object.

Comment: You can use ```data=simplejson.dumps({"parentValue":{"value1":False,"value2":None}})```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As roganjosh suggested, `json.dumps()` on the object needed, works.

Answer (score -1):

rather than using `data=simplejson.dumps({"parentValue":{"value1":False,"value2":None}})` you should use

```
json = {"parentValue":{"value1":False,"value2":None}}
```