# Make HTTP request without double quotes in json

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I want to make a POST HTTP request using requests library by including json parameters as follows:

```
r = requests.post(url, json={"field1":"value1", "field2":"null", verify=False)
```

Field2 value must be null and the server expects null without double quotes "null".
I have also tried to assign null to a variable:

```
variable = "null"
r = requests.post(url, json={"field1":"value1", "field2":variable, verify=False)
```

But the request is made by including double quotes. How can I make the request to have the json value of field2 being only null without quotes?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass null as a value in a POST request on python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404949/how-do-i-pass-null-as-a-value-in-a-post-request-on-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code lacks closing bracket `}` before `verify=False`:

```py
r = requests.post(url, json={"field1":"value1", "field2":"null"}, verify=False)
#                                                              ^
```

---

If you want to set JSON field to `null`, set its python equivalent to `None`:

```py
import requests

r = requests.post(url, json={"field1": "value1", "field2": None}, verify=False)
#                                                            ^
```